# Versionar app em Cordova

Tags: ionic, versionamento

Tenho um aplicativo feito com Ionic + Cordova e gostaria de começar a versioná-lo para melhor controle e começar a distribuir só que eu esqueço de alterar a versão manualmente a cada build alem de não ser nada prático. Alguém conhece uma forma automática de fazer o controle?
OBS: Não vou distribuir em nenhuma loja de app.

Answer (score 1):

Foi isso que me ajudou a resolver [Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/automatic-build-numbering/9283/11).
Segui o passo a passo certinho e adaptei o código as minhas necessidades.
Cada vez que eu dou build a versão incrementa como no exemplo:
v 1.0.0 > Build v 1.0.1 :)